# s:iterator with collection of Object array

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

I have a `ArrayList` which contains a list of `Object` array **Eg:** `new Object ['a','b','c']`

The list is a member variable of data object.

Now, how can I access each 3 element data while iterating it in the `s:iterator` tag loop

```
<s:iterator value="data.list" status="cnt" var="searchList">

  <s:property value="searchList[0]"/>
  <s:property value="searchList[1]"/>
  <s:property value="searchList[2]"/>

</s:iterator>
```

I tried above code, but it displayed nothing.

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/2237/struts-2-control-tags-example-tutorial

Comment: You are just missing `#` in front of `searchList` in `<s:property>` tag. (e.g. `<s:property value="#searchList[0]"/>`).

Comment: @AleksandrM thank you for spotting `#`

Comment: @AleksandrM would you like to help me out of this  http://stackoverflow.com/q/41501453/3425489

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```jsp
<s:iterator value="data.list" status="cnt" var="searchList">
  <s:property value="#searchList[0]" />
  <s:property value="#searchList[1]" />
  <s:property value="#searchList[2]" />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: You can use Object array as above

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:iterator value="data.list" status="cnt" var="searchList">
  <s:property value="#searchList"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: This won't get elements from the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property directly by the index

```
<s:iterator value="data.list" status="cnt" var="searchList">
  <s:iterator begin="0" end="data.list.length" var="idx">    
    <s:property value="[1].data.list[%{#idx}]}"/>
  </s:iterator>    
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Because you are not iterating list.

Comment: the list has elements, so it's iterating, why not?

Comment: Well yes list is iterating. :) But you are not getting elements from list iteration.

Comment: Is this better? Why not getting?

Comment: thanks roman and alek..by the way why # in needed? is it needed to be a OGNL to be work? Why value="data.list" in s:iterator doesnt need the #. This "data.list" is also OGNL right?

Comment: @Harshana # is used to access context variables (directly)

Comment: when i use <s:property value="#searchList"/> i guess by default it prints the first element but how can i access the whole array object. For example suppose i need to assign the array object to it to a java scriplet variable. <%Object[] row = (Object[])%><s:property value="#searchList"/>;

Comment: @Roman # is used to access context variables (directly). what you mean by directly? How come we can access <s:iterator value="data.list"> here without the #

Comment: It prints the *current* element reference pushed into the Value Stack. By directly I mean it will not *search* the value stack, without it the value stack is searching the whole stack.

Comment: how can assign the array object directly to a scriplet?

Comment: @Roman i try below <s:property value="#manageUsersFormNew.pagingTO.list[#cnt.index]"/> and even <s:property value="#top.searchList"/> return empty